# Swift singlelinkedlist node not cut off list

Tags: swift

There is one thing I do not quite understand, for example:

```
public class Node {
  var val:Int
  var next:Node?

 init(_ val:Int) {
  self.val = val
  self.next = nil
 }
}

func printList(_ node:Node?) {
  var cur = node
  while cur != nil {
   print(cur!.val, terminator: " ")
   cur = cur.next
  }
 }

 var l1 = Node(1)
 var l2 = Node(2)
 var l3 = Node(3)

 l1.next = l2
 l2.next = l3
```

Now when I do `printlist(l1)`, it prints:

```
1 2 3
```

which is correct.

What if I set `l2.next = nil` then `printList(l1)`? The output is: `1 2`, which I can understand.

What I don't understand is if I set `l2 = nil` then `printList(l1)`, it still prints `1 2 3`.

Why does it not print `1` as the second node has become nil, so it should cut off the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable l2 is a *reference* to the Node(2) object. Setting l2 to nil does not affect the object itself, only removes that reference. Node(1).next still references Node(2) and Node(2).next still references Node(3)

You might picture the initial setup like this

```
l1 -> Node(1)
        |
        v
l2 -> Node(2)
        |
        v
l3 -> Node(3)
```

And after setting l2 to nil, like this

```
l1 -> Node(1)
        |
        v
      Node(2)
        |
        v
l3 -> Node(3)
```

Neither l2, nor l3 for that matter, are relevant when evaluating printlist(l1)

If the intent is to remove Node(2) from the list update Node(1).next to Node(3). eg.

```
l1.next = l3
```

You picture looks like this:

```
l1 -> Node(1) ---|
                 |
                 |
l2 -> Node(2)    |
                 |
                 |
l3 -> Node(3) <--|
```

Comment: so Dale , what is the best way to cut off the linked list, I want to cut off L2, let this linkedlist become 2 List, one is L1( which only have one node) the other is  L3

Answer (score 0):

This is because L2 was referencing a node object in memory and setting it as L1.next also made L1.next refer to that same object in memory. So setting L2 to nil means L2 variable should no longer reference the node object but L1.next remains unchanged and still points to the node object.